Maghrib valid if prayed at home after traveling
If one is traveling during maghrib or isha and arrives home after isha starts, is maghrib prayer still valid if you pray it at home? Or must we pray maghrib while traveling for it to be valid?

It is unclear what you are trying to ask. The prayer must be performed within its proper time, regardless of whether you do it while traveling or on reaching home. If you delay it such that the time of the next prayer comes then it would have to be offered as a Qada.

We can combine isha and maghrib while traveling. If we delay maghrib and arrive home during the time of isha, is maghrib prayer still valid?
